# understanding closures and their scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm having trouble understanding closures and scope.  I was pretty certain I understood it until I got unexpected behaviour.

```
function doSomething () {
    // Code unrelated to frag

    var rightDiv = document.createElement(rightDiv);

    var img, i, frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < photoIDs.length; i++){
        img = new Image();
        addClass(img, "popup-image-preview");
        img.src = "photos/"+photoIDs[i]+".jpg";
        frag.appendChild(img)
    }
    // add popup for preview
    addEvent(rightDiv, "mouseover", function() {
        showPopup(frag, this);
        console.dir(frag);
    });

    // more code unrelated to frag
}
```

I expected that the onmouseover handler would still have access to the DocumentFragment containing the images.  But when I view it in the console, it no longer has any children.  Is it not true that this specific anonymous function has access to the values of the local-variables for *this specific* execution of **doSomething** or will subsequent calls to doSomething affect closures of previous executions?  The latter would make my situation understandable, as subsequent calls to doSomething may have an empty **frag** .

Comment: I believe that that closure should work as expected. Weird.

Comment: AFAIK, your assumptions are right, this must have a different reason or you hit some corner case...

Comment: I wonder if it is because you're re-invoking `doSomething`, and re-binding your event?  Not sure if this will throw out the old event binding or not (don't know JS in the browser that well).

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WxQDk/2/.

Comment: Ah.. So if I remove the invocation of showPopup(..), the console outputs as expected.  This is my bad obviously.  **showPopup** appends the document fragment to a div.  And I'm assuming that when this occurs, the DocumentFragment object is emptied of children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the closure does work as expected.  My fault was in `showPopup` where I was appending `frag` to a document node.  I was unaware that this would consequently empty the DocumentFragment.  I am now using `node.appendChild(frag.cloneNode(true))` in `showPopup`.

Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken, you are right and your code should work like you expect. But there are a few things which make we wonder:

- where is `rightDiv` defined? It looks like you're adding more and more `mouseover` events to that "node" since it's not part of the context.
- do `addEvent` or `showPopup` modify anything on the `frag` variable ?

Comment: sorry.. yeah. I made an edit now explaining it is unique to each execution.

Comment: @rewolf: can you please show the code, where it is declared and how it is defined ?

Comment: I added the line of its definition. **doSomething** is basically creating a div containing information and another div, rightDiv, which allows you to view images in a popup.  But there are many of these divs, each created by **doSomething**, some without popups.

Comment: Thanks. It was showPopup's fault.  I didn't realise that appending a DocumentFragment to a node would empty the DocumentFragment of children.  I'm using cloneNode now.